# Minimize function with trust-ncg method proposes value greater than max_trust_radius

Tags: python, scipy, scientific-computing

So far I understand the minimize function with method Trust-ncg, the "method specific" parameter "max_trust_radius" is the maximum value for a  new step optimization. 
However, I experience a weird behaviour. 
I work in my doctorate data and I have a code that invokes minimize function (with trust ncg method) 
passing parameters

```
{
   'initial_trust_radius':0.1,
   'max_trust_radius':1,
   'eta':0.15,
   'gtol':1e-5,
   'disp': True
}
```

I invoke minimize function as:

```
res = minimize(bbox, x0, method='trust-ncg',jac=bbox_der, hess=bbox_hess,options=opt_par)
```

where

- `bbox` is a function to evaluate the objective function
- `x0` is the initial guess
- `bbox_der` is the gradient function
- `bbox_hess` hessian function
- `opt_par` is the dictionary above with the parameters.

Bbox invokes simulation code and get the data. It works: minimize go back and forth, proposing new values, bbox invokes simulation.

Everything works well until I got a weird issue. 
The "x" vector contains 8 values. I realize that one of the iterations, the last value is greater than 1. 
Per the max_trust_radius, I think that it should be less than 1, but it is 1.0621612802208713e+00 
The issue causes problems because bbox can not receive the value greater than 1, as it invokes a simulation program and there is a constraint that it can not receive 1 or greater than 1.

I found the scipy code and tried to see if I could be able to find a bug or something wrong but I am not.

My main concerns are:

- My understanding is that there is a bug in the scipy minimize code as the new value is greater than max_trust_radius .
- How can I manipulate or control the values to avoid that values became greater than 1?
- Do you suggest something to investigate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `max_trust_radius` controls how large **steps** you are allowed to take:

```
max_trust_radius : float
                   Maximum value of the trust-region radius.
                   No steps that are longer than this value will be proposed.
```

Since you are very likely to take many steps during the minimization, each which can be up to `1` long, it is not strange at all that you (assuming `||x0||=0`) end up with `||x|| > 1`.

If your problem is strictly bounded then you need to apply an optimization algorithm that supports bounds on the parameters.
For `scipy.optimize.minimize` only `L-BFGS-B`, `TNC` and `SLSQP` methods seem to support the `bounds=` keyword.